# TikZ-UML is possible to have association with more than 2 angles? how to have special arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-uml

i have to insert an UML into my pdf but it's a little bit complicated. I have done every association easily but there is the last one that is impossible to do because needs more than 2 control node (then 2 angles) e more than 3 arms/arch/arrows. In fact, without them the arrow that link this 2 classes goes behind the other classes present in the UML resulting not really visible.

I would like to know if there is a workaround, because the geometry that is accepted (horizontal-vertical-horizontal or vertical-horizontal-vertical) is not enough, in my case would be useful HVHVH geometry.

[image: I would like to follow the red path or at least the green one]

I would like to follow the red path or at least the green one

EDIT: added MWE

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[%
corpo=12pt,
oldstyle,
autoretitolo,
tipotesi=magistrale,
greek,
evenboxes,
a4paper,
%twoside=true,
%open=right,
titlepage,
%headinclude,
%footinclude,
%BCOR=12.5mm,
%numbers=noenddot,
cleardoublepage=empty,%tablecaptionabove
]{toptesi}
\usepackage{../tikzuml-v1.0-2016-03-29/tikz-uml}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \umlinterface[x=-8,y=+4]{IInteractor}{}
        {       
            + activeInteractor(GameObject gOb) : void  \\
            + passiveInteractor(GameObject gOb) : void
        }
    
        \umlclass[x=-8]{ObjectInteractor}{}
        {
            - Awake() : void \\ 
            - initializeInteractableObject() : void \\
            \umlvirt{+ activeInteractor(GameObject gOb) : void} \\
            \umlvirt{+ passiveInteractor(GameObject gOb) : void}
        }
    
        \umlclass[x=-8, y=-4]{Colorator}
        {
            - SpriteRenderer m\_SpriteRenderer;
        }
        {
            - Start() : void \\ 
            + activeInteractor(GameObject gOb) : void \\
            + CombineColors(params Color[] aColors) : Color
        }
    
        \umlclass{GameObject}{...}{...}
    
        \umlinterface[y=-8]{IColorable}{}
        {       
            + toColor() : void
        }
    
        \umlclass[x=-8,y=-8]{bgColorable}
        {
            - SpriteRenderer m\_SpriteRenderer;
        }
        {
            - Start() : void \\ 
            + toColor() : void \\
            + toColor(Color color) : void
        }
    
        \umlclass[x=-8,y=-12]{textColorable}
        {
            - TextMeshPro bcText;
        }
        {
            - Start() : void \\
            + getText() : void \\ 
            + toColor() : void \\
            + toColor(Color color) : void
        }
    
        \umlunicompo[geometry=-|]{Colorator}{GameObject}
        \umlinherit[geometry=-|]{Colorator}{ObjectInteractor}
        \umlreal{ObjectInteractor}{IInteractor}
        \umlreal{bgColorable}{IColorable}
        \umlreal{textColorable}{IColorable}
        %\umlimport[geometry=-|,anchors=-10 and 90]{Colorator}{IColorable}
        \umldep[geometry=-|,anchors=-10 and 90]{Colorator}{IColorable}
        %\umlCNunicompo[geometry=-|-,anchors=180 and 0, arm1=-2cm, arm2=8cm, align1=left, align2=right]{bgColorable}{-13,-8}{-13,-15}{2,-15}{GameObject}
        %\umlCNunicompo[geometry=|-|, anchors=-30 and 0]{bgColorable}{3,-12}{GameObject}
        \umlunicompo[geometry=-|-,anchors=-0 and 0, arm1=8cm]{textColorable}{GameObject}
    
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your issue is not a very hard one and as said above, we don't want to do it from scratch. You will certainly have an answer when provided a MWE.

Comment: I'll add my working example soon. I thought it wasn't necessary because i only asked a method if exist, not the solution. but the solution itself would be appreciated. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that when using some specialized packages they are actually a set of commands and nests that allow you to draw something in a few commands; but as you can see there is no option in the code to do what you require, so you just have to use the basic tikz code to achieve the objective; Of course you should check the code of the package to at least know if the names of the nodes and the styles that invoke each variant of arrows can be reused, as is the case.

For this case the styles are in these lines:

```
%Line 209
\tikzstyle{tikzuml association style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, -]%
    \tikzstyle{tikzuml bidirectional association style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, angle45-angle45]%
    \tikzstyle{tikzuml unidirectional association style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, -angle 45]%
    \tikzstyle{tikzuml aggregation style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, open diamond-]%
    \tikzstyle{tikzuml unidirectional aggregation style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, open diamond-angle 45]%
    \tikzstyle{tikzuml composition style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, diamond-]%
    \tikzstyle{tikzuml unidirectional composition style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, diamond-angle 45]%
    \tikzstyle{tikzuml nesting style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor]%
    \tikzstyle{tikzuml dependency style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, -angle 45, dashed]%
    \tikzstyle{tikzuml import style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, -angle 45, dashed]%
    \tikzstyle{tikzuml inherit style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, -open triangle 45]%
    \tikzstyle{tikzuml implements style}=[color=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, -open triangle 45, dashed]%
```

Obviously, for this case, it is not possible to provide an **MWE** that should be copied and compiled without problems to see the result, since it requires you to download the package to some local address on your computer. But nothing complicated of course, in this case I changed the document class to **standalone** that I recommend you use , since it will allow you to get your graphics independently of your main document, where then you can place them using the graphics package, at the scale that suits you best. But it is a matter of taste of course.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE IF (YOU DOWNLOAD [TIKZ-UML-v1.0-2016-03-29](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ekielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=download) AND PLACE IT IN THE FOLDER OF YOUR TEX FILE):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzuml-v1.0-2016-03-29/tikz-uml}%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \umlinterface[x=-8,y=+4]{IInteractor}{}{
            + activeInteractor(GameObject gOb) : void  \\
            + passiveInteractor(GameObject gOb) : void
        }
    
        \umlclass[x=-8]{ObjectInteractor}{}{
            - Awake() : void \\
            - initializeInteractableObject() : void \\
            \umlvirt{+ activeInteractor(GameObject gOb) : void} \\
            \umlvirt{+ passiveInteractor(GameObject gOb) : void}
        }
    
        \umlclass[x=-8, y=-4]{Colorator}{
            - SpriteRenderer m\_SpriteRenderer;
        }{
            - Start() : void \\ 
            + activeInteractor(GameObject gOb) : void \\
            + CombineColors(params Color[] aColors) : Color
        }
    
        \umlclass{GameObject}{...}{...}
        
        \umlinterface[y=-8]{IColorable}{}{
            + toColor() : void
        }
        
        \umlclass[x=-8,y=-8]{bgColorable}{
            - SpriteRenderer m\_SpriteRenderer;
        }{
            - Start() : void \\
            + toColor() : void \\
            + toColor(Color color) : void
        }
        \umlclass[x=-8,y=-12]{textColorable}{
            - TextMeshPro bcText;
        }{
            - Start() : void \\
            + getText() : void \\ 
            + toColor() : void \\
            + toColor(Color color) : void
        }
    
        \umlunicompo[geometry=-|]{Colorator}{GameObject}
        \umlinherit[geometry=-|]{Colorator}{ObjectInteractor}
        \umlreal{ObjectInteractor}{IInteractor}
        \umlreal{bgColorable}{IColorable}
        \umlreal{textColorable}{IColorable}
        \umldep[geometry=-|,anchors=-10 and 90]{Colorator}{IColorable}
        \umlunicompo[geometry=-|-,anchors=0 and 0, arm1=8cm]{textColorable}{GameObject}
        
        %Some basic tikz code here using node names declared in package commands...
        \draw[diamond-angle 45,red]
        (Colorator.180)
            -| ++(-0.5,-10)
            -| ($(GameObject.10)+(1.2,0)$)
            -- (GameObject.10);
        
        \draw[diamond-angle 45,green!50!black]
        (bgColorable.-10)
            -| ++(1.5,-2)
            -| ($(GameObject.-10)+(0.9,0)$)
            -- (GameObject.-10);    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works. I am not so expert with LaTeX, so i didn't know how to use tikz, I studied tikz-uml on the fly and used it because was simple and not understanding if there were some internal method to obtain what i needed i asked for it. I never used tikz and for this reason I was avoiding it to gain some time instead to study how it works hoping there was a easy solution with tikz-uml. But I will take tikz documentation soon because it is a powerfool tool.